# Owl Carousel display none after inserting some images to div using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

I'm using `Laravel`. What I'm trying to do is to insert some divs to `.content`
Bassically I `select some data from database` and insert using `javascript` in `.content`

I'm using `owl carousel` for sliding images.
The problem is that, the `owl carousel` is `called` before I select the data and inner to `.content` and its `display none` because there is no .`item-images` at the time the owl carousel is loaded.

The question, is how can I make to fix this?

I've tested with adding a timeout to owl carousel for 5 seconds and is working, but when you visit the site there is a little deelay when images appear (of course because of 5 sec timeout) and I don't want users to experience that.

index.blade.php

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="list" id="list">
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(document).ready(() => {
    var owl2 = $('.item-images').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        dots: true,
        nav: true,
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false,
        mouseDrag: false,
        smartSpeed: 500
    });
})


$.ajax({
    url: 'api/getItemsFromDb', 
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        user: '1'
    },
    success: function (c)
    {
        innerItemsToContent(c);                                  
    },
    error: function(e)
    {
       console.log(e);
    }
});


function innerItemsToContent(item)
{
    var container = document.getElementById("list");
    if(container)
    {
        item.forEach(e => {
            container.innerHTML += `
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="title">${e.title}</div>
                    <div class="message">${e.message}</div>
                    <div class="item-images owl-carousel" id="img_insert"></div>
                </div>
            `;

            var container_img = document.getElementById("img_insert");

            for(var i = 0; i < e.count_pictures; i++)
            {
                console.log('test');
                container_img.innerHTML += `
                    <img src="assets/tools/img_posts_test/${e.img[i].img_laravel_name}.${e.img[i].img_type}" name="${e.id} item id" class="img-item-style">
                `;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

API.php (Controller)

```
public function getItemsFromDb(Request $r)
{
    $r->validate([
        'user' => 'required'
    ]);

    $data = DB::table('items')->where('item_id', '=', 1)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->limit(1)->get();
    $img = DB::table('images')->where('belongs_to_item', '=', 1)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();

    foreach($data as $d)
    {
        if($d->count_pictures > 0)
        {
            $count = 0;
            foreach($img as $i)
            {
                $d->img[$count] = $i;
                $count++;
            }
        }

    }


    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set append new data via Ajax, when your ajax function complete - you must set callbak function to refresh you carousel:

1. copy you carousel options into new var
2. call carousel init

   ```
   var optionsAfterAjax = {
      items: 1,
      dots: true,
      nav: true,
      loop: false,
      autoplay: false,
      mouseDrag: false,
      smartSpeed: 500
    }
    $(".item-images").owlCarousel(optionsAfterAjax);
   ```

Comment: Is working, my question is, If I do that, is creating and replacing the first owlCarousel that was created or is creating another owlCarousel above the first one?

Comment: As i know - it's just re-init (re-start) all Carousels with class `".item-images"`
Simply - call `.owlCarousel` initialization, and the new initialization takes into account the same (but updated via ajax) html code of carousel items.

Comment: So it's RE-create the same Carousels))